# Flutter How make status and navigation bar is completely transparent

Tags: android, flutter

I'm noticing when open my app there are 2 screens to reach to my first flutter screen

1 - 1st screen has gray  or (50% transparent) status and navigation bar black and light icons.
2 - 2nd screen has 100% transparent status and navigation bar and white icons.

How Can I make all screens like 1st flutter screen 100 transparent status and navigation bar with black icon (Brightness Dark).

**1st screen**

[image]

**2nd screen**

[image]

**1st flutter screen**

[image]

**style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- You can name this style whatever you'd like -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

**Edit**

Now I have change my code the 1st screen is correct but 2nd screen still icon is white color and background is also white , I want show icons as black.

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- You can name this style whatever you'd like -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val window: Window = getWindow()
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        
     
    }
}
```

**Status bar / 2nd screen**

[image]

**Navigation bar / 2nd screen**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For status bar transparent in flutter screen

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
   SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      //color set to transperent or set your own color
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, 
      //set brightness for icons, like dark background light icons
   )
);
```

For dark and light icons:

```
AppBar( 
   brightness: Brightness.dark,
   //Brightness.light = Dark icon
   //Brghtness.dark = Light icon
)
```

Reference link : https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/12/how-to-make-status-bar-transparent-and-icon-light-dark-flutter/

**Edit**:
If you want make native splash screen transparent :

Launch Theme

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
         Flutter draws its first frame -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Window


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val window: Window = getWindow()
        window.setStatusBarColor(0x00000000)
    }
}
```

main.dart

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Color(0x00000000),
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Note: As per flutter issues(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64001) this only works in release mode , there is a flicker of in debug mode.

**Edit 2:**
Remove `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>` and  `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>` from the Normaltheme as this is setting the white color in your code.
AppTheme/LaunchTheme is used by first screen(native splash) while first flutter screen(2nd screen you see) uses NormalTheme.

Update style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- You can name this style whatever you'd like -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have tried these solution but not  it's working correctly .

Comment: What's the issue you are facing. First screen in android native code (which according to you is now correct),  For second screen , you need to update you NormalTheme as this is used for flutter screens ,